# Livewire does not keep value

Tags: php, laravel, forms, frontend

I have a form where I set a mount of one ingredient, but the form takes value of wire:model that is using, but i want to show value o "value"

Function is working, and im sure form is taking value of model:wire and not from value

Im using Laravel 10 with livewire 3.4

```
<input 
type="text" 
id="floating_filled_medida" 
value="{{ number_format($ingrediente->cantidad * $porcentaje, 2) }}"
wire:model="cantidadEdita.{{$ingrediente->id}}"
wire:change="guardaCambiosCantidad({{$ingrediente->id}})"
/>
```

```
    public function cambiaRecetaActual(){
        //cambia receta
        $this->recetaActual = $this->recetas->firstWhere('id',$this->cambiaReceta);
        $this->actualizaVista();

        //cambia ingredientes
        $aux = $this->recetaActual->x*$this->recetaActual->y*$this->recetaActual->z ;

        $this->porcentaje = $aux/$this->unidad;
    }
```

This is the main view
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ET3H.png)

But when I change first option, "medida" must change
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xOxrV.png)

If I comment wire:model works.
`{{-- wire:model="cantidadEdita.{{$ingrediente->id}}" --}}`
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQ8Jh.png)

How can i show the value?